# Finding current through a resistor in a tricky circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits

What are the (a) size and (b) direction (up or down) of current i in Fig, where all resistances are 4.0 Ω and all batteries are ideal and have an emf of 10 V? (Hint: This can be answered using only mental calculation.)

[image]

---

I'm pretty sure KCL/KVL are not the right strategy here. There must exist a clever way to solve this.

My approach 1 :  I've tried to find a loop which contains only batteries and the resistor in question, but it seems there is no such trivial loop. Stuck.

My approach 2 : I've simplified series parallel resistors where they give integer equivalent resistances. But the resultant circuit is still not that simple. Stuck. Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: @JohnRennie I'm not looking for the final answer. This is not really my homework, I'm just doing for fun :)

Comment: You might want first to consider the “outsidemost” loop, containing batteries and a single resistor, as your way in.

Comment: Why the downvote ?

Comment: it’s basically a homework question.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Oh yes, nice observation. I think the current through the resistor in that outerloop would be $0$ because all the batteries cancel each other out ?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I see it falls under homework category, but why the downvote ? I've spent a few hours on solving this before posting it here. Also it is not my homework. Just doing it to kill time..

Comment: wasn’t mine so I dunno.  You *are* asking people for straight help, on which enough has already been given.

Comment: Ohk.. thank you for the hint about outer loop, you've a really good eye :)  Since the current through that bottom most resistor is $0$, I can remove it and the resulting circuit should be equivalent to the old..

Comment: It will be nice if you can discuss such questions in chat room  since you have enough rep to access it

Comment: @Abhinav how to access chat ?

Comment: click on the button on the rightmost corner of the screen and there will be rooms like h bar and problem solving strategies for discussing such problems

Comment: @Abhinav it is not showing on my screen. I only see "Related" and "How Network Questions"  on the right side ?

Comment: @rsadhvika topmost right side..there will be a stack exchange site symbol(kinda like a square)

Comment: @Abhinav Gotcha! Ty :)